# Given Required Steps, Return Minimum

Tags: c++

So say in a given input you are given a something like:

```
[ [1,2], [3,4], [2,5], [5,4], [1,3], [2,6] ]
```

The first number is the required step for the second step (number) to run.  1 is required for 2 and 3 to run, 3 and 5 are required for 4 to run, etc.  How can we create an output of steps run so everything can run in minimum steps.  So for example the result for this one would be :

```
[ [1], [2, 3], [6,5], [4]]
```

Input / Output can be Vector, LL, etc.

This is an extra problem in my textbook I was working on that I cannot figure out after hours of attempts?  Any help?  I would love to see how this would be solved.  I was attempting in C++.

Comment: Looks like the thing you are looking for is *topological sorting*.

Comment: Look up Kahn's algorithm.

Comment: Take out a piece of paper, and write down in short, brief, English sentences an outline of the algorithm that implements this task. This is not very complicated, and the solution can be explained in just a few tasks. Once you're done [make an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Present your solution to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck agrees that your proposed solution works, simply take what you've written down and translate it into C++. Mission accomplished.